# Python Beautiful Soup 'NoneType' object error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

I am using Beautiful Soup to get hyperlinks in the body of web pages. Here is the code I use

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.1914-1918.net/swb.htm'
element = 'body'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for elementSoup in pageSoup.find_all(element):
  for linkSoup in elementSoup.find_all('a'):
    print linkSoup['href']
```

I got an AttributeError when I tried to find hyperlinks for the swb.htm page.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'

I am sure that there are a body element and a couple of 'a' elements under the body element. But strangely it works well for other pages (e.g. http://www.1914-1918.net/1div.htm).

This problem has been haunting me for days. Can anyone please point out what I did wrong.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Post-edit, your code reflects @Hal's answer. Exactly which is your code, this one post-edit or the one pre-edit?

Comment: I post-edited my code. The print problem @Hal pointed out was a typo. Sorry for all the confusions.

Comment: Kindly check if you're using the latest BeautifulSoup release and Python 2.7.6. I am getting a boatload of links on this without problems. I can see in your screenshot that you have Python 2.7, but humor us and try checking if it's 2.7.5+. :)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 2.7.3. I guess this could be the reason for this problem. Don't want to risk breaking dependencies to upgrade to 2.7.6. Any other solutions maybe?

Comment: I am trying this out in Python 3 and it worked very well. Cheers

Comment: You should be using virtualenv when running Python on Ubuntu btw. I use Ubuntu 13.10, and both with a virtual environment of 2.7.6 and the built-in 2.7.5+ system Python, this works well. Weird that it should work for 3.x for you. Oh well. Good luck. :)

Comment: I believe this is still an open bug in BeautifulSoup:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1270611

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have the html5lib installed.

Just try remove it and test again.

More details:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1184417

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the beautifulsoup4 is not fit your Python, try removing beautifulsoup4: `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4`, and install the older version: `pip install beautifulsoup4==<version>`, I use the version `4.1.3`.

Comment: never try to revert to older version if it's not a very well and documented bug that requires that.